# Cannot get value of textbox by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

javascript

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {                                  
        var userName = jQuery("#userName").val();

        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            alert(userName);

        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="contact">
    <div class="contact-form">
        <h2>Check Out</h2>
        <div>
            <span><label>Name</label></span>
            <span><input name="userName" type="text" class="textbox" id="userName"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the value of the textbox. It is always empty when I click the button. Please help me to the value of the textbox to use with ajax.

Comment: +1 for at least using the combination of the shortcut jQuery DOM ready with locally scoped `$`. I don't see many others using it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the username once at page load time, before you register the click handler, and then never getting it again.

You need to get the value *fresh* inside of the click handler.

```
    jQuery(function ($) {                                  

        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            var userName = $("#userName").val();
            alert(userName);

        });
    });
```

Note, you are scoping a local `$`, so please use it instead of `jQuery` *inside the DOM ready handler* :)

Comment: Thank TrueBlueAussie,I did it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function( $ ) {
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            alert($("#userName").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you replaced the shortcut DOM ready handler with scoped `$` with the older version? They had that part correct.

Comment: I'm pleading ignorance, since I was unaware of the 'newer' version.  Do you have a link or quick explanation?

Comment: Edited my answer.  Is that correct?  What is the advantage, here?

Comment: *Now the circle is complete* :) It is shorter and avoid clashes with other plugins that use a global `$`.